# .Net Linq - Doing a operation on the subset

Tags: vb.net, linq, .net-3.5

I need to have the following : (name1 + "a") + (name2 + "a") + ...

```
Dim separator() As String = {"|"}    
myString.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.None).SomeLinq(...)
```

I don't know what to add at the end to add an "a" to each element...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Select` in this case:

```
Dim separator() As String = {"|"}    
myString.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.None).Select(Function(s) (s + "a"))
```

`Select` can be used as a "conversion" function this way, too.  After this, you can convert back to your one string:

```
String.Join("|", myString.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.None).Select(Function(s) (s + "a")).ToArray())
```

My apologies if the VB.Net is slightly off; I'm a C# developer, typically.

Answer (score -2):

User StringBuilder and foreach()

EDIT: OOps, I don't know VB.NET, only C#, so use whatever the equivalent is of foreach